# how to make webpage compatible to every screen size

Tags: xhtml

I have three tables in my web page which combinely takes up full space of a 15.6 inch screen.
But when someone open the website in a 14 inch pc/laptop,the right sidebar goes more to its right and the middle table goes inside the left sidebar making the whole page looking very ugly.
plz help me 
the link of the website is:  http://www.bestindiacollege.com/

Comment: FYI you should not think of screen sizes based on the physical measurement of the screen. Screens are measured in pixels and 2 15.6 inch screens can have different pixel widths. Some 15 in screens have 800 pixels wide, some have 1280 and most can be set by the user to various values. On a large wide screen monitor your layout is seriously messed up.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use liquid css layout or javascript (which is less favorable solution imo).

You can check [code for liquid layouts here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C13/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure this is a question for SO, so it might get migrated, but it was not hard to do: http://www.google.com/search?q=webpage+for+every+screen+size

You can choose the advise that best fit your purpose. The range of options is wide. For your webpage, I would choose either a fixed small size (maybe reducing one column for the images) or a width:80%

The options (randomly chosen and assorted)

> You use a table in your web pages that is of a fixed size. The table width should be fixed at 700 pixels wide, and all your web page content sits inside this table.

or

> Build your pages in 100% width tables

or

> In Search of the Holy Grail: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holyg…
>   http://www.elated.com/articles/choosing-…
>   How to create flexible sites quickly using standards like CSS and XHTML: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/li…
>
> 960 Grid System: http://960.gs/
>
> Care With Font Size: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/font-size

or

> Before you start you need to decide on your lowest screen resolution. Your web site will have to be designed keeping the lowest resolution in mind. Through our research we have found that less than 0.5% are on the 640 x 480 resolution So we ignore that completely. The next important resolution is the 800 x 600 resolution. Some of our visitors are on this resolution so we use this as our lowest screen resolution. This means that our web site has to fit all resolutions equal to or higher than 800 x 600.

or

> The best advice on screen resolution is available from usability expert, Jakob Nielson. He says to optimize for 1024 x 768 and to make your site “liquid” so that it stretches for any resolution. You can view his detailed advice at this link: http://www.useit.com/alertbox/screen_resolution.html

or

> Fluid vs. Static Layout
>
> A fluid layout can expand and contract depending on the screen resolution of the user. If including lower resolutions is important but you don't want to have completely different designs, a fluid layout might be what you are looking for. There are many templates out there for fluid CSS and HTML layouts. And if you don't want to use a template, custom coding a fluid isn't that hard. But that's for another article.
>
> A static layout is a layout the has a set width and doesn't change with the users screen resolution. While a static layout is viewable on hand held devices, users have to scroll to the sides to view content that doesn't fit on the screen, which can get annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheels you may opt a grid based layout system. This [article](http://www.significantpixels.com/2010/12/10/responsive-grid-systems/) gives an overview. [Media Queries](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) may also help.